# A single word that describes trying to obtain something you might not actually get?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to retrieve an object so that I can use it. Normally I would use the word "get" here so I would end up with "get X".

However, there is the possibility that my attempt to retrieve the object will fail, preventing me from using it and actually performing work.

I'm looking for a word that reflects my attempt at getting it whilst also acknowledging the possibility of failure.